# Error on Zabbix: /server-status 404: Not Found.

Tags: apache, zabbix

I've been dealing with this whole day and still can't figure it out.
I've setup Zabbix on one machine, and I want to monitor the Apache server on another machine.
I've completed all the steps described in the docs: http://www.zabbix.com/wiki/templates/apache
and still I get no data in the Apache Template. When checking the logs on the Apache server, I can see in access.log:

```
IPADDR - - [16/Jul/2012:13:29:08 +0000] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.0" 404 13826 "-" "Python-urllib/1.17"
```

I think it might has something to do with Virtual Servers and additional sites I have on that machine, but I can't figure it out, and nothing mentioned in the docs...

Answer (score 1):

The Apache checks are not as clever as you may think.

Can Zabbix communicate with your apache server? Link it to a template with something simple like "uptime" and verify that it indeed gets data.

Next, verify that there aren't any firewall rules prevent the zabbix server from communicating with your web server. Can you curl your homepage from the zabbix host without problems?

Are the apache checks active checks? If so you'll need to make sure active checks are enabled in the /etc/zabbix/zabbix-agentd.conf file and that the "Hostname" within the conf is unique and matching up correctly with what you have in the zabbix server.

If that fails, change the DebugLevel to 4 in /etc/zabbix-agentd.conf and tail the zabbix log. Look and see if it is having trouble with any checks.

Comment: Can you suggest solution for NGINX?

Answer (score 0):

This is an apache configuration problem, zabbix can't do anything if `/server-status` yields a 404 error.

Maybe the `<Location /server-status>...</Location>` directive is not at the right place in apache's configuration.

Try to move it inside the `<VirtualHost>` section of the specific virtual server to which the `GET /server-status` is routed.

Also make sure that [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) is enabled.

Comment: Can you suggest solution for NGINX?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar issue, I updated the end point URL by appending the port number on which zabbix was running.

For Ex:

Previous Endpoint: http://127.0.0.1/api_jsonrpc.php

Updated Endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:8080/api_jsonrpc.php